# Convert Eigen to numpy matrix

Tags: python, c++, numpy, eigen, code-conversion

I have the following code in C++ that uses the Eigen library, need help to translate to python (numpy)

Initialization

```
double b = 20.0;
Eigen::Vector3d C(1.0/10.2, 1.0/10.2, 1/30);

Eigen::MatrixXd U(5200, 3);
int i = 0;
for (double x = 10.2/2.0; x < 200; x += 10) {
    for (double y = 10.2/2.0; y < 200; y += 10) {
        for (double t = 0; t <= 360; t += 30) {
            U(i, 0) = x;
            U(i, 1) = y;
            U(i, 2) = psi;
            i += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Function:

```
Eigen::VectorXd operator()(const Eigen::VectorXd& s) {
    Eigen::VectorXd p(length());

    p(0) = s[0];
    p(1) = s[1];
    p(2) = s[2];
    p(3) = s[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < U.rows(); i++) {
        p(i + 4) = b*exp(-0.5*(s.tail(U.cols()) - U.row(i).transpose()).dot(C*(s.tail(U.cols())
                            - U.row(i).transpose())));
        if (p(i + 4) < 0.1) {
            p(i + 4) = 0;
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

*Python version*

Initialization:

```
my_x = 10.2/2.0
my_y = 10.2/2.0
my_p = 0

xx = []
while my_x < 200:
    xx.append(my_x)
    my_x += 10

yy = []
while my_y < 200:
    yy.append(my_y)
    my_y += 10

pps = []
while my_psi <= 360:
    pps.append(my_p)
    my_p+=30

U =[]
for x in xx:
    for y in yy:
        for p in pps:
            U.append([x,y,p])

U = numpy.matrix(U)

C = numpy.array([1.0/10.2, 1.0/10.2, 1.0/30.0])

b = 20.0
```

*The Function*

Instead of `operator()` I will call the function `doSomething()`

```
def doSomething(s):   # Where s is a numpy array (1-d vector)
    p[0:4] = s[0:4]
    for i in range (U.shape[0]):
        s_dash = -0.5*(s - U[i].T)
        s_ddash = C*s
        s_dddash = s_dash.dot(s_ddash) - U[i].T
        p[i+4] = b * numpy.exp(s_dddash)

        if p[i+4] < 0.1: p[i+4] = 0
```

What I am confused:

1. In the C++ implementation, I think `p[i+4]` is supposed to be a single value
2. In my python version, I get a `p[i+4]` as square matrix
3. Each `p[i+4]` is a zero matrix.

I am unable to decipher my mistake. Please help!

Comment: try printing s inside doSomething, see what you get. Is it really a 1-d vector?

Comment: also, the line `for i in range U.shape[0]:` should be `for i in range(U.shape[0]):`

Comment: `s` is a 1 d vector indeed

Comment: `U[i]` is the `i`th _row_ of your matrix, so `U[i].T` is a _column_ array. When you subtract it from the 1d (~row) array `s`, you get a matrix via array broadcasting. Side note: you should use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix` as the former is more flexible and you don't seem to actually be using matrix methods (and the same problem wouldn't arise with arrays because then `U[i]` would be a 1d array so `U[i].T` would be identical to `U[i]`: a 1d array).